# NGINX sending a big file will not send all data in some cases

Tags: php, nginx

I have a simple movie file(mkv) that i'm sending over nginx.

My Nginx Config is the following

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

worker_rlimit_nofile 300000;
events {
    worker_connections  16000;
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    gzip off;

    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    server {
        listen 5050;
        index index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/;
        server_tokens off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$ ) {
            return 200;
        }

    }
}
```

If i try to download the movie from a fast connection (for example with wget from a server) the movie is being downloaded successfully.

If i try to fetch the movie using slower connection, for example using ffmpeg with the -re argument (native frames), it will only download the half of the movie. The same of course happens if i use wget and adjust the download speed to be much lower than the normal one.

The connection from nginx  closes after some time without sending the whole file, and i dont understand why this is happening and why it doesn't happen if i have a fast connection.

***EDIT***

i Edit my post entirely, because after running some tests i find out that the issue is coming from NGINX, and not from PHP as the connection was still closing after fetching the movie directly from nginx.

Comment: Are you sure you did try to set the `max_execution_time` to `0` by calling `set_time_limit(0)` at the begging of your script? How long it takes for the slow connection to fail after the download starts?

Comment: hello, i edited my post as it isn't php issue i think. The movie is 20 minutes, and always ends at exactly the same time 8 minutes and few seconds (usually 30).

Comment: You have to do it with a different way and use Nginx [XSendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/). I did it, and I have a **5GB** file transfering for about **22** minutes so far without interruption at **20K/s** using `wget`. I can write an answer with my working example if you want.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said in the beginning, this seems to be a problem with [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php), try to increase the value, make sure that you can adjust this value, some servers don't allow this.

Comment: i tried with that too. Didn't work. Also when i have slow connection it closes after 8 minutes not some seconds, and the entire movie is 20 minutes.

Comment: If your server is shared, even adjusting set_time_limit() to another value, it will reset to it's default value. Is your server shared or do you have enough permissions to change this PHP value?

Comment: it's a dedicated server, i can do anything. I have root user.

Comment: Hello, i run some tests and i find out that the nginx is causing the problem, as fetching the movie directly from nginx causes the same issue , so it is not php related. I edited my first post.

Comment: Oh, I even thought about a problem on Nginx too, it must be some timeout / time_limit nginx configuration.